# Installing a new font for Miktex 2.9 / TexMaker: Source Sans Pro

Tags: fonts, miktex2.9, sourcesanspro

I have checked the Miktex Package Manager and the package sourcesanspro is already installed. 
But when I put "\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}" into my code, Texmaker says: "Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succed for the following reason: The SourceSansPro-Regular-Lf-t1-base source file could not be found. ...."

Can someone help, please?

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}


%%% === PAKETE  === %%%
%% --- Allgemein --- %%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                         % Sonderzeichen
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                            % westeuropäische Zeichen
\usepackage[english,german,ngerman]{babel}                                          % Rechtschreibung catalan,
\usepackage{lmodern}                                                                % Verbesserung Lesbarkeit Schrift
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}       
\usepackage{microtype}                                                              % Verbesserung Schriftbild
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[format=hang,skip=2.5pt,justification=RaggedRight,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}                                       % Bulletpoints in Tabelle
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr0.85\linewidth-3\tabcolsep\relax}}{#1}}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}                                                 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}


% -- Nummerierung/Benennung von Tabellen/Grafiken - %
    \renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}
    \renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\tablename}{Tab.}


%% --- Grafiken erstellen --- %%
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}


\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
        \scalebox{3}{

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-500:500,smooth,node distance = 0cm, auto]


\node [anchor=center] at (0,0) {Verlust};



\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Call on a command line `updmap`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you very much. Now it works fine.